# ListView "hiding" child elements

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, scrollview, carousel, code-behind

Hello All and Happy New Year!
I've been searching a lot not finding answers. So my question is why does a ListView, CarouselView, ScrollView elements "hide" its child elements? To clarify testing I put a simple Grid and add a few radiobutton (x:name="radButton1") and a corresponding label (x:name="label1") (redundant but radiobuttons currently do not display its Text value) and image. From code behind I can access them all with radButton1.GroupName, label1.Text, etc. no issues. However as soon as I move them into my ListView, CarouselView, ScrollView and go back to code behind I get errors that radButton1, label1, image, etc. that they are no longer in the current context unable to retrieve by Name value?
I tried to get at the listview element and then look at children but that doesn't show me those elements so that I can modify them like there Text value or IsVisible, etc. At this point I really am only concerned with the CarouselView as that is what gives me the better look and feel for a user interaction.

okay here is my XAML code and code-behind

```
<Image x:Name="greenCheck" Source="GreenCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GreenCheck}"></Image> 
<Image x:Name="GrayCheck" Source="GrayCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GrayCheck}"></Image> 
<Image x:Name="greenCheck1" Source="GreenCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GreenCheck1}"></Image> 
<Image x:Name="GrayCheck1" Source="GrayCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GrayCheck1}"></Image> 
Codebehind: 
GrayCheck = false; 
GreenCheck = true; 
GrayCheck1 = true; 
GreenCheck1 = false;
```

This is getting set but doesn't display a green check on either option user selects?

TIA!
Cheers!
Rick...

Answer (score 0):

Because all of those controls are **templated**.  You cannot access templated elements by name.

If you have a single `Label` on your page and assign it an `x:Name` *myLabel* in XAML, the XAML compiler creates a variable named **myLabel** that you can use to reference that control from your code behind.

However, if you have a `ListView` that has a `Label` in it's template, there may be 0, or 12, or 1000 copies of that `Label` generated at runtime depending on the number of items in your `ItemsSource`.  You cannot refer to it by name because it is not a single instance, it is 0 to many instances.

You should use databinding to tie properties of your UI to your *ViewModel*, and update your *ViewModel* at runtime to make changes to your UI.  This is part of the MVVM pattern.  You should not directly modify UI properties of templated controls at runtime.

Comment: Ah okay thanks Jason. I was thinking something like that but thought I'd better ask. The thing is what I really need to do and I was with bindings to the x:Name to make each 1 unique name so I can control a specific image and/or label but simply unsure how to go about this. This is a very simple personal app only so again I have been able to set the binding data but again unsure how to retrieve them in code? Could you point me to an example and maybe I already seen a few but what they were doing was not what I really need but then again maybe I do and I'm just not following the reasoning.

Comment: you need to include a property in your model with the path or url of the image you want to display for each row

Comment: if you want a more specific example please update your question to describe a specific problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Okay understand but it is how do I use it for controlling in this case visibility of an image? What I am specifically needing to do is set visibility of an image (checkmark) on/off based on a user selection from 1 of 2 button per "page" a button the user clicks so they can see 1 they answered question and 2 they can visually see what they selected (e.g. click button 1 turn on an image, click button 2 ensure image 1 is off and turn image 2 on and vice-versa). It is a toggle if you will of the users selection. There are specifically 16 items 2 on each carousel view so total 8 carousel swipes.

Comment: bind your images IsVisible property to a bool in the model, and then when the user changes their filter selection, iterate through your ItemsSource and set that property appropriately

Comment: okay here is my XAML code and code-behind
<Image x:Name="greenCheck" Source="GreenCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GreenCheck}"></Image>
<Image x:Name="GrayCheck" Source="GrayCheckmark.gif" IsVisible="{Binding GrayCheck}"></Image>

Codebehind: GrayCheck1 = false;
                   GreenCheck1 = true;
                   GrayCheck2 = true;
                   GreenCheck2 = false;

This is getting set but doesnt display a green check on either option user selects?

TIA!
Rick...

Comment: please [edit] your question to add details and code, don't stuff them in a comment.  And if your IsVisible is bound to property "GreenCheck" why are you setting "GreenCheck1" in the code behind?

Comment: Sorry I had edited and renamed to lower character count. I also had removed 2 of the image and edited the wrong ones. Corrected in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> However as soon as I move them into my ListView, CarouselView, ScrollView and go back to code behind I get errors that radButton1, label1, image, etc. that they are no longer in the current context unable to retrieve by Name value?

As Jason said that you can not access control by Name in ListView template, you can change control value by viewmodel.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <ListView
            x:Name="listview"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding radiomodels}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout>
                            <RadioButton
                                x:Name="radiobutton1"
                                GroupName="images"
                                Text="{Binding radiobutton1text}" />
                            <RadioButton
                                x:Name="radiobutton2"
                                GroupName="images"
                                Text="{Binding radiobutton2text}" />
                            <Switch x:Name="switch" IsToggled="{Binding ischeck, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Image IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsToggled, Source={x:Reference switch}}" Source="{Binding image}" />
                            <Label Text="this is test" />
                            <Button
                                x:Name="btn1"
                                Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
                                Text="button" />
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btnupdate"
            Clicked="btnupdate_Clicked"
            Text="update listview item" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<radiomodel> radiomodels { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radiomodels = new ObservableCollection<radiomodel>()
        {
            new radiomodel(){radiobutton1text="radio button1",radiobutton2text="radio button2", ischeck=false,image="a5.jpg"},
            new radiomodel(){radiobutton1text="radio button1",radiobutton2text="radio button2",ischeck=false,image="a6.jpg"},
            new radiomodel(){radiobutton1text="radio button1",radiobutton2text="radio button2",ischeck=false,image="a7.jpg"},
            new radiomodel(){radiobutton1text="radio button1",radiobutton2text="radio button2",ischeck=false,image="a8.jpg"},
            new radiomodel(){radiobutton1text="radio button1",radiobutton2text="radio button2",ischeck=false,image="a9.jpg"}

        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

   
    private void btnupdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radiomodel item = (radiomodel)listview.SelectedItem;
        var changeitem = radiomodels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.image == item.image);
        if(changeitem!=null)
        {
            changeitem.radiobutton1text = "test";
        }
    }
}

public class radiomodel:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _radiobutton1text;
    public string radiobutton1text
    {
        get { return _radiobutton1text; }
        set
        {
            _radiobutton1text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("radiobutton1text");
        }
    }

    private string _radiobutton2text;
    public string radiobutton2text
    {
        get { return _radiobutton2text; }
        set
        {
            _radiobutton2text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("radiobutton2text");
        }
    }
    private bool _ischeck;
    public bool ischeck
    {
        get { return _ischeck; }
        set
        {
            _ischeck = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ischeck");
        }
    }

    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

}

If you still want to get control in ListView, you can follow the code below to get ListView selected row control.

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = sender as Button;
        StackLayout stacklayout =(StackLayout) button.Parent;
        RadioButton radiobutton1 = (RadioButton)stacklayout.Children[0];

        radiobutton1.Text = "test";

    }
```

The ViewModelBase is class, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface, to notify data updated.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cherry for reply. I now understand this a lot more and controlling via bindings in my viewModel as shown above in edited response to Jason. I simplified code in codebehind that is getting fired on button click and during debug they are getting properly set however graycheck still is visible and greencheck is still invisible. Is there something more required after setting the values in codebehind due to the imagebuttons are contained inside a carousel view? There are 32 check images (16 gray, 16 green)?

Comment: @Rick If GrayCheck and GreenCheck  are property,  this class implements INotifyPropertyChanged to notify data changed? I suggest you can take a look [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#a-simple-viewmodel) firstly.